# google cloud platform - mySQL access denied from compute engine instance with public IP

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I set up a public IP connection using the manual [Connecting using a public IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine#gce-connect-ip). However, when I try connecting from my compute engine instance to MySQL instance using the command: `mysql --host=<MySQL instance IP> -user=<user> --password`, I get `mysql Access denied for user.. @ (using password: YES)`.
The user\password is correct and is working from my local client BUT not from my compute engine instance.

Compute engine instance: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

mySQL instance version: MySQL 5.7

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: This is a MySQL permission problem and not a GCP problem. You need to `GRANT` MySQL access to that user arriving from that IP address. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-grant.aspx/

Comment: Side-note: Make sure you are using MySQL SSL otherwise your login and password are sent clear text. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connections.html

Comment: The MySQL instance is opened to all IPs, the user host field set to % and no SSL is configured. As I mentioned before, I can use this user from my local machine BUT NOT from my compute engine.

Comment: MySQL considers a user connecting from localhost to have different permissions than the same username coming from an external IP. Read up on MySQL permissions and the GRANT statement. Note: I strongly recommend using the Google Cloud SQL Proxy to connect to your instance over the Internet. Otherwise you should have SSL configured before allowing Internet authentication.

Comment: the issue was that in case some special characters in the password, it can be changed by bash terminal

Comment: If your MySQL password contains any of these characters, the password must be surrounded by quotes. `* ? [ < > & ; ! | $ ( )`. Example: `--password='PASSWORD'`

Answer (score 0):

This issue related to MySQL configuration.

**To solve your issue** you should follow steps below:

1. [Find](https://www.whatismyip.com/) the external ip of the client host.
2. Connect to your MySQL VM instance via SSH.
3. Connect to mysql and [modify](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-user.html) your existing user:

   ```
   RENAME USER 'bob'@'localhost' TO 'bob'@'XXX.226.XXX.220';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

   or [create](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html#create-user-overview) a new one:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'bob'@'XXX.226.XXX.220' IDENTIFIED BY 'secure_password';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bob'@'XXX.226.XXX.220';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
4. (Optional) Check connection (*your login and password are sent without encryption*):

   ```
   $ mysql -u bob -h YYY.71.YYY.6 -p
   Enter password: 
   ...
   mysql>
   ```
5. Follow step by step instructions [1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04) or [2](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-ssl-and-remote-connections-for-mysql-on-centos-7/) and configure SSL/TLS encryption for remote connections accordingly to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connections.html).

Comment: the MySQL instance is opened to all IPs and the user host field set to `%`.
As I mentioned before, I can use this user from my local machine BUT NOT from my compute engine.

Comment: I've checked my commands using two VM instances. Please try to follow my steps with IPs.

Comment: I tried both options describe in section 3 but, sadly, both of them end up with the same `Access denied` result.

Comment: Please update your question with your commands and outputs.

Comment: the issue was that in case some special characters in the password, it can be changed by bash terminal

Comment: Thanks, it could be useful for community. Please upvote my answer if it was helpful for you.